# Method ListsResources.getUserListMemberships not recognized in Twitter4J 4.0.4

Tags: java, twitter4j, nomethoderror

when calling

```
twitter.list().getUserListMemberships(userId, 1000,1,false);
```

I get this error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: twitter4j.api.ListsResources.getUserListMemberships(JIJ)Ltwitter4j/PagableResponseList;
```

I read the javadoc for this method (see [here](http://twitter4j.org/javadoc/twitter4j/api/ListsResources.html#getUserListMemberships-java.lang.String-int-long-boolean-)), and I don't see what I am doing wrong? And I did verify that my dependencies are OK. Any clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just use Twitter4j 4.0.2 and that method doesn't exist
[image: 4.0.2]

But on Twitter4j 4.0.4 does exist
[image: 4.0.4]

So, Are you sure that you are using 4.0.4?
Keep in mind too that you are using cursor 1 on the first call but you have to use -1. I just run this code and works

```
    User user = twitter.showUser("lt_deportes");
       long cursor = -1;
        PagableResponseList<UserList> lists;
                do {
            lists =  twitter.list().getUserListMemberships(user.getId(),1000,cursor,false);
            for (UserList list : lists) {
                System.out.println("id:" + list.getId() + ", name:" + list.getName() + ", description:"
                        + list.getDescription() + ", slug:" + list.getSlug() + "");
            }
        } while ((cursor = lists.getNextCursor()) != 0);
```

Comment: Thanks for helping on the diagnosis! It pushed me to look again, and indeed I had an older version of Twitter4J in the libs of GlassFish, bypassing the dependency I had defined in my POM...